# AppSync query sortField: "ceatedAt" set to descending order

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

From this schema.graphql below it returns 10 posts from the oldest post to latest when I query userPosts.

```
type User @model {
  id: String!
  posts: [Post] @connection(name: "UserPosts", sortField: "createdAt")
}
```

How do I set this order to DESC so it returns latest 10 posts instead of oldest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a `@model` type using Amplify CLI, it generates your schema with a query called `listPosts`. This query has multiple parameters, one of them being `sortDirection`, which is of type `ModelSortDirection`.

ModelSortDirection is an `enum` type and has the following shape:

```
enum ModelSortDirection {
    ASC
    DESC
}
```

You can pass `DESC`. Moreover, if you edit the `posts` Resolver, from the API Schema page of your [AppSync console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/appsync/home), you can see how this parameter is being used. It uses the DynamoDB [scanIndexForward](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#API_Query_RequestParameters) to sort the rows coming back from your DataSource.

```
  "scanIndexForward":   #if( $context.args.sortDirection )
    #if( $context.args.sortDirection == "ASC" )
true
    #else
false
    #end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where can I see the Resolver? I can find ```  "scanIndexForward":   #if( $context.args.sortDirection )
    #if( $context.args.sortDirection == "ASC" )
true
    #else
false
    #end``` anywhere in my codebase

Comment: Updated my answer. Sorry I missed it. You can log into your AppSync Console and click on Schema page for your API. You should see the Resolvers section on this page, where you can find the link to edit this resolver.

Comment: Got ya! Thank you!

Comment: U meant adding `enum ModelSortDirection {
    ASC
    DESC
}` into schema.graphql and run `amplify push`?

Comment: You don't need to. It's generated by amplify cli

Comment: How do I pass `DESC` to the query with `await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getUser, {id: username}))`?

Comment: Try passing `DESC` without quotes, to the `sortDirection` parameter in your query. I found a couple of helpful articles looking up on Google:
https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/653 and https://medium.com/graphql-mastery/how-to-design-graphql-mutations-and-queries-part-2-enums-ebb01613832

Comment: I found that modifying `graphql/queries.js` file with `sortDirection` works but still not sure how to pass it from my React component rather than modifying `graphql/queries.js` to `posts(limit: 10, sortDirection: DESC) {...`

Comment: U meant doing something like `API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getUser, {id: username, posts: {sortDirection: DECS}}))`? which does not work